# serializing the object containing the function - Meaning

Tags: python, apache-spark

The below text is from Chapter 3 of [Learning Spark](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028512.do)

> One issue to watch out for when passing functions is **inadvertently
>   serializing the object containing the function**. When you pass a
>   function that is the member of an object, or contains references to
>   fields in an object (e.g., self.field), Spark sends the entire object
>   to worker nodes, which can be much larger than the bit of information
>   you need (see Example 3-19). Sometimes this can also cause your
>   program to fail, if your class contains objects that Python can’t
>   figure out how to pickle.

[image]

Please explain what message the author trying to convey here.

Comment: Frankly I think the author is wrong because they don't understand how variables work in Python. In the supposedly safe example, `query` is just another name for `self.query`, so the result would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Workers in distributed systems don't have shared memory, hence each worker has to have a copy of all the functions, data etc it might need to run the code. Hence, when you make calls that are supposed to be distributed, you should try to reduce this overhead by making sure that you are not copying stuff the worker doesn't really need.

In this example `rdd.filter` is a vectorised (functional) operation that can be distributed across several workers. It takes a single argument - a function. The author warns you, that if that function references a field (attribute) of any object (`self` is the internal term objects use to reference themselves, so you basically reference the very object that will call the `filter` methods inside its own method), the entire object (instance) will be copied to the worker, not just a lightweight function. And the object can contain many attributes referencing a lot of data.